# VBA Code works differently in different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a simple VBA code, which copies a column and pastes it in another column without the empty cells, which are in the original column. It works in the woorkbook, where I wrote it. But I copied it to another one, where I need it. It copies the the needed cells more than once and it fills the whole column the these values.

```
Range("f5:f2500").ClearContents                             

 With Range("d5:d2500")                                      

    .Offset(, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, _  
    xlNumbers).Copy                                                 
    .Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial skipblanks:=True, _            
    Paste:=xlPasteValues                                            

 End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sub` below will copy the formulas (with values in cells) from column D, and paste their values in column F, starting from Cell "F5" and down (without blanks).

The `Sub` receives the `Worksheet.Name` as an argument, so all the `Range`s inside are fully qualified with that certain worksheet's name.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumnWOBlanks(wsName As String)

With Worksheets(wsName)
    .Range("F5:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

    .Range("D5:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy
    .Range("F5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, skipblanks:=True
End With

End Sub
```

This `Main` sub below, is just for testing, modify it to fit your needs.

```
Sub Main()

CopyColumnWOBlanks ("Sheet5") ' <-- change "Sheet5" to whatever worksheet you want the macro to run

End Sub
```